# Pytorch error - too many dimensions 'str'

Tags: python, pytorch

I use the following code to pad the sentences:

```
    corpus = [
        "We always come to Paris",
        "The professor is from Australia",
        "I live in Stanford",
        "He comes from Taiwan",
        "The capital of Turkey is Ankara"
    ]
    def preprocess_sentence(sentence):
        return sentence.lower().split()
    
    # Create our training set
    train_sentences = [sent.lower().split() for sent in corpus]
    padded=nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(torch.tensor(train_sentences), batch_first=True, padding_value="<pad>")
```

This gives an error:

```
ValueError: too many dimensions 'str'
```

Comment: torch.tensor does not accept a list of str that is what is causing the ValueError. The solution would be to do some kind of encoding convert the strings to int and then go ahead with padding.